# Oracle SQL is not a group by expression

Tags: sql, oracle

When I run this code

```
SELECT sales_date AS DAY, SUM (TOTAL_AMOUNT_RM) 

FROM SALESINVOICE

GROUP BY SALES_DATE

order by sales_date;
```

it gives me a table which is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tnp45.png)

Then I run the other code

```
SELECT SR.DAY, SUM(SR.PROFIT_RM) AS TOTALPROFIT_RM

FROM

(SELECT SALESINVOICE_ID AS NO, S.ITEM_ID AS ITEM, SALES_DATE AS DAY, S.QUANTITY, C.PRICE_RM, C.COST_RM, ((S.QUANTITY*C.PRICE_RM)-(S.QUANTITY*C.COST_RM)) AS PROFIT_RM

FROM SALESINVOICE S

INNER JOIN (SELECT ITEM_ID, PRICE_RM, COST_RM FROM ITEM I ) C

ON S.ITEM_ID = C.ITEM_ID
ORDER BY SALESINVOICE_ID, SALES_DATE) SR 
GROUP BY SR.DAY

ORDER BY SR.DAY;
```

which gave me a table [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaMI2.png)

I try to inner join both table, but when I try to call the column sum(total_amount_rm), it gives me an group by expression error

```
SELECT SR.DAY, SUM(SR.PROFIT_RM) AS TOTALPROFIT_RM, D.TOTAL

FROM 

(SELECT SALESINVOICE_ID AS NO, S.ITEM_ID AS ITEM, SALES_DATE AS DAY, S.QUANTITY, C.PRICE_RM, C.COST_RM, ((S.QUANTITY*C.PRICE_RM)-(S.QUANTITY*C.COST_RM)) AS PROFIT_RM

FROM SALESINVOICE S

INNER JOIN (SELECT ITEM_ID, PRICE_RM, COST_RM FROM ITEM I ) C
ON S.ITEM_ID = C.ITEM_ID
ORDER BY SALESINVOICE_ID, SALES_DATE) SR

INNER JOIN (SELECT SALES_DATE AS DAY, SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT_RM) AS TOTAL FROM SALESINVOICE GROUP BY SALES_DATE ORDER BY SALES_DATE) D

ON D.DAY = SR.DAY

GROUP BY SR.DAY

ORDER BY SR.DAY;
```

However, it can run without the selection of D.TOTAL. Can anyone help me? I am sql newbie

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not as images (or links to images.)

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because with `GROUP BY`, in `SELECT` clause, all columns that is not in the `GROUP BY` clause must come with an aggregate function

To solve it, one way is calculating sum  before joining

```
SELECT s.day, s.totalprofit_rm, d.total
FROM 
(
    SELECT sr.day, 
        SUM(sr.profit_rm) AS totalprofit_rm
    FROM
    (
        SELECT salesinvoice_id AS no, 
            s.item_id AS item, 
            sales_date AS day, 
            s.quantity, 
            c.price_rm, 
            c.cost_rm, 
            (s.quantity * c.price_rm) - (s.quantity * c.cost_rm) AS profit_rm
        FROM salesinvoice s
        INNER JOIN (SELECT item_id, price_rm, cost_rm FROM item) c
        ON s.item_id = c.item_id
    ) sr
    GROUP BY sr.day
) s
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT sales_date AS day, 
        SUM(total_amount_rm) AS total 
    FROM salesinvoice 
    GROUP BY sales_date
) d
ON d.day = s.day
ORDER BY s.day;
```

And this above query could be rewrite to be shorter:

```
SELECT sr.day, sr.totalprofit_rm, d.total
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        s.sales_date AS day, 
        SUM((s.quantity * c.price_rm) - (s.quantity * c.cost_rm)) AS totalprofit_rm
    FROM salesinvoice s
    INNER JOIN item c
    ON s.item_id = c.item_id
    GROUP BY s.sales_date  
) sr
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT sales_date AS day, 
        SUM(total_amount_rm) AS total 
    FROM salesinvoice 
    GROUP BY sales_date
) d
ON d.day = sr.day
ORDER BY sr.day;
```